# Firebase Cloud Messaging / Pushing Notification to Web platform using JavaScript is not receiving the message

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Now I am developing a Web application that needs to use the live-notification feature. I am using Google Firebase's Cloud Messaging service. I can successfully register the service and retrieve the token value using JavaScript. But when I push the message from the REST Client, my platform is not triggering the onMessage event.

This is my full code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FCM</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is the FCM</h1>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxx",
        authDomain: "fcm-web-testing.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://fcm-web-testing.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "fcm-web-testing",
        storageBucket: "fcm-web-testing.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){
        console.log(messaging.getToken());
        return messaging.getToken();
    }).then(function(token){
        //I get the token here. I use this token to push the notification
        console.log(token);
    })
        .catch(function(err){
            alert('Permission denied');
        })

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
        //I am expecting to trigger this event when I push the message using the REST client
        alert('Message ' + payload)
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I commented out in the code to highlight what I am expecting to get. I can retrieve the token which I commented in the code. When I get the token, I push the message from the REST client like this.

My request body is something like this

```
{
    "to" : "dJA57nVCZ7A:APA91bFFaYODxZQ4tbyy6RupRvH-jhmM1xh8F3iBQ1BWwdnvHA-dbB50cY1OyYNLpNhZLIKZm7Aqs4nTnQDsd2sExvNIglAeMSw3VLDXGjgaeqBEYFgz6PqbOJIS0Qki6m9XQ931H1xt",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "SOMETHING",
        "title" : "SOMETHING"
    },
    "data" : {
      "message" : "This is data message"
    }
}
```

As you can see I pass the token retrieved previously to the request body. I also passed server key in the header as well. Post request was successful. I got the following response message.

[image]

But on successful request, the event in the Javascript code should be fired.

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
            //I am expecting to trigger this event when I push the message using the REST client
            alert('Message ' + payload)
        })
```

But, it was not triggered. Actually, it is supposed to be trigged after the successful post request has been made. What is wrong with or missing in my code?

Answer (score 1):

How do you serve your web app? It must be served over http**S** [(Description)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client), otherwise the ServiceWorker / Messaging won't work.

Have a look at the Developer Console (Chrome) -> Application -> Service Workers, your SW should appear here.

**Edit:**

For testing you can also upload your project into firebase hosting. There is a free ssl cert. included.
To do so, install the firebase cli (via [npm](https://nodejs.org/en/)):

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then, first run the login command to log into your google account:

```
firebase login
```

and 'init' a new project (like `npm init`):

```
firebase init
```

Deploying then is as easy as typing

```
firebase deploy
```

Have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) for more details.

Comment: Now, it is over http. But localhost. It should work. I will try to fake the https on localhost and try it again.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I could not manage to install ssl for my localhost. So I ended up using Pusher (https://pusher.com/channels?campaignid=916184871&adgroupid=48337812880&adid=264982473776&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0bvWq-bg3AIV7pztCh3AYQw2EAAYASAAEgJpsvD_BwE) instead. It is even better.

Comment: if it solved your problem, please consider marking it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You no need to have https when testing locally. Just http://localhost:<< port>> works fine.
If you deploy your site on to a domain(not localhost), then it has to be http**s** to get firebase service worker working.

1. you will get notification only when the window is minimised/not focused.
2. if window is in focus, directly onmessage event will be fired.
3. Try below JSON Posts:

Below push handled by firebase serviceworker internally(if you use firebase hosting) you don't need to handle it with setBackgroundMessageHandler in your sw.

```
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "body": "5 to 1",
    "icon": "firebase-logo.png"
  },
  "to": "ecce7xlo9CA:APA91bEXPT-NCnl9evVE....",
  "priority": "high"
}
```

Below will not be handled internally, you need to setBackgroundMessageHandler in your sw.

```
{
  "data":{
    "id": 1,
    "missedRequests": 5,
    "addAnyDataHere": 123
  },
  "to": "ecce7xlo9CA:APA91bEXPT-NCnl9evVE....",
  "priority": "high"
}
```